# Функция возвращающая объект

Tags: ооп, java

Добрый день, друзья!

Имеется следующий код:

```
class FileInfo 
{
 public static String NameFile;
 public static String TypeFile;
 public static int SizeFile;
 public static String DateCreate;
 public static String DateEdit;      
}
```

И другой класс:

```
public class View_files_folders
{
  public ??? getItem(int number)
  {

   }
}
```

- Вопрос первый как сделать, чтобы
     функция getItem возвращала класс
     FileInfo?
- Второй вопрос, есть ли специальные в Java типы данных даты и времени, если да, то какой модуль надо подключать? Чтобы поля DateCreate и DateEdit по возможности не делать типом String.
- Как сделать чтобы getItem возвращала объект?

Comment: С такими вопросами вам сначала нужно обратиться к документации/книге/урокам по Java (например http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ )

Comment: У меня нету времени читать учебник. Надо сделать это задание как можно быстрее, а Java я к сожалению пока не знаю, в интернете только нахожу информацию и по логике как в других языках делаю. На форумах тоже прошу помощи. вот так... не минусуйте меня за незнание...(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2) `Date, GregorianCalendar`
Сторонняя: `JodaTime`

Comment: Стоить отметить, что `java.util.Date` используется для хранения значения даты, а наследники `java.util.Calendar` - для манипуляций с датой/временем.

Answer (score 3):

```
public FileInfo getItem(){}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а что с остальными вопросами?

Comment: 2) насколько я помню, нет
3) не понял вопроса
4) return new SomeClass();

Answer (score 1):

В Java 8 появилась замечательная библиотека для работы со временем:
[Статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216431/)